# MFMailComposeViewController usage and Apple aproval process

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, appstore-approval

In my app, I have a logs mechanism, which offer the possibility to the customer to send the logs via mail.For this, I integrated in my app the Apple MFMailComposeViewController. In case that the customer use a device with low OS version (2.x) or an e-mail account isn't presented on the device, I pushed some UIAlertsView with some suggestive messages for users. Can somebody please take a look over my below code, and reply if there is something that could lead to a rejection by Apple?

```
BOOL canSendmail = [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail];

if (!canSendmail) {


    NSMutableString* osVersion = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]];
    EventsLog* logs = [EventsLog getInstance];

    if ([osVersion characterAtIndex : 0] == '2'  || [osVersion characterAtIndex : 0] == '1' ) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Email", @"") 
                                                        message:NSLocalizedString(@"Failed to send E-mail.For this service you need to upgrade the iPhone OS to 3.0 version or later", @"")
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"") otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];



        [logs writeEvent : @"Cannot send e-mail - iPhone OS needs upgrade to at least 3.0 version" classSource:@"LogsSessionDetailViewController@sendEmail" details : (@" device OS version is %@",osVersion)];

        return;

    }
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Email", @"") 
                                                    message:NSLocalizedString(@"Failed to send E-mail.Please set an E-mail account and try again", @"")
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"") otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

    [logs writeEvent : @"Cannot send e-mail "  
          classSource:@"LogsSessionDetailViewController@sendEmail" details : @"-  no e-mail account activated"];

    return;
}



UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Email", @"") 
                message:NSLocalizedString(@"The data you are sending will be used to improve the application. You are free to add any personal comments in this e-mail", @"")
                delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"") otherButtonTitles: nil];

[alert addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Submit", @"")];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Many thanks,

Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't say about appstore admission/rejection but your code must crash on iPhone OS 2.x - you call

```
BOOL canSendmail = [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail];
```

without checking if this call is possible (MFMailComposeViewController class is not available on 2.x system). Also manual checking of OS version is not a good practice. Instead you must at first check if `MFMailComposeViewController` present in current runtime:

```
if ( !NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController") ){
    // Put code that handles OS 2.x version
    return;
}

if (![MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
    // Put code that handles the case when mail account is not set up
    return;
}

//Finally, create and send your log
...
```

P.S. Do not forget that you must set linkage type for MessageUI framework as 'weak' in target settings - you application will crash on old systems on start if you linkage type will be 'required' (default value).

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir.I didn't think at this one - indeed that would crash :).